# Trigger CircleCI workflow using GitHub App

Tags: circleci, dbt, github-app

I've installed dbt apps in a GitHub repo following this doc[1], so DBT could run jobs whenever a push is made to the repository. I'm now trying to add some checks at CircleCI, which should also be triggered whenever a commit is made to the repo.

The thing is that any commit made using DBT Cloud IDE fails to trigger CircleCI with the message
"Block unregistered user"

I then noticed that the user appearing as the one triggering the job was the dbt app and not the user who commited, leading then to the error above.

Is there a way to allow github apps to trigger circleci jobs ? I've found this thread[2] on CircleCI Discuss, but given it was answered a while ago, I was hoping anything changed on this. Or maybe some setup change on DBT side and not on CircleCI ?

Any help is much appreciated

[1] https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/collaborate/git/connect-github

[2] https://discuss.circleci.com/t/add-a-github-app-user-to-a-restricted-context/34775